# check Memory leaks in windows

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

I have used valgrind in Linux. Can anyone tell me some similar tools for checking memory leak  in windows?

Comment: Possible repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows

Comment: **Duplicate** : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows

Comment: You should use deleaker to find memory leaks...

Answer (score 2):

[AppVerifier](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457063.aspx) will check for memory leaks, as well as many other kinds of Windows-specific errors.

Answer (score 2):

The similiar topic was discussed in here:
[Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Leak Detector](http://vld.codeplex.com/) is a good tool to check App in DEBUG Mode.